# Jenkins pipeline - how to start node.js app from one node and use it in different node?

Tags: node.js, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing a jenkinsfile and trying to start node.js app from node A and then use it from node B.
I tried many ways, but in all of them - when i'm moving from node A to node B, the app is shutting down..
Any idea?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

are you nodes containers or pods?

if you're running Jenkins on kubernetes slaves (https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin ) the slaves ( pods ) will shutdown if not being used by Jenkins.